# Different results in image classifier using JPG BMP

Tags: tensorflow, classification

I trained an Image Classifier with Tensforflow using a bunch of JPG images.
Let's say I have 3 classifiers, ClassifierA, ClassifierB, ClassifierC.

When testing the classifiers, I have no issues at all in 90% of the images I use as a test. But in some cases, I have misclassifications due to the image quality.

For example, the image below is the same, saved as BMP and JPG. You'll see little differences due to the format quality.

When I test the BMP version using tf.image.decode_bmp I get misclassifications, let's say ClassifierA 70%

When I test the JPG version using tf.image.decode_jpeg I get the right one, ClassifierB 90%

When I test the JPG version using tf.image.decode_jpeg and dct_method="INTEGER_ACCURATE" I get the right one with the much better result, ClassifierB 99%

What could be the issue here? Such difference between BMP and JPG, and how can I solve this if there's a solution?

[image: Example]

update1: I retrained my Classifier using different effects and randomly changing the quality in which I save the images I use as a dataset.

Now, I get the right output, but still the percentages changes a lot, for example44% with BMP and +90% with JPG

Answer (score 1):

This is a fabulous question, and even more fabulous of an observation. I'm going to use this in my own work in the future!

I expect you have just identified a rather fascinating issue with the dataset. It appears that your model is overfitting to features specific to JPG compression. The solution is to increase data augmentation. In particular, convert your training samples between various formats randomly.

This issue also makes me think that sharpening and blurring operations would make good data augmentation features. It's common to alter color, contrast, rotation, scale, orientation, and translation of the image to augmentat the training dataset, but I don't commonly see blur and sharpness used. I suspect these two data augmentation techniques will go a long way to resolving your issue by themselves.

In case the OP (or others reading this) are not terribly familiar with what "data augmentation" is, I'll define it. It is common to warp your training images in various ways to generate endlessly unique images from your (otherwise finite) dataset. For example, randomly flipping the image left/right is quite simple, common, and effectively doubles your dataset. Changing contrast and brightness settings further alter your images. Adding these and other data augmentation transformations to your pipeline creates a much richer dataset and trains a network that is more robust to these common variations in images.

It's important that the data augmentation techniques you use produce realistic variations. For example, rotating an image is quite a realistic augmentation technique. If your training image is a cat standing horizontally, it's realistically possible that a future sample might be a cat at a 25-degree angle.

Comment: I retrained my Classifier using different effects and randomly changing the quality in wich I save the images I use as a dataset.

Now, I get the right output, but still the porcentages changes a lot, for example44% with BMP and +90% with JPG

Comment: When you say "percentages still look good" I assume you mean the confidence that the classifier has in a particular prediction? So if I understand, you got an improvement by doing the data augmentation, but not perfect right? I am surprised doing the data augmentation doesn't resolve the issue entirely. I'm not actually sure how else to attack the problem.

Comment: Exactly, I got an improvement getting the right prediction, but there is still +30% prediction percentage beetwen BMP and JPG.